# How can I initialize the new pyqt window?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

1. Click on the main window (A) to open a new window (B).
2. Save the value at B. The example code saved the name through fileopen.
3. If you close B and open B again through a click, the previously saved value remains.

All I want is to click and reset all the values.

Also, even if A is shut down while B is open, B remains.

I also want to know how to solve this problem.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class CombineClass(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CombineClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint, False)


        self.label = QPushButton("file name", self)
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.fileselect)
        self.label.move(150,100)

        self.label2 = QLabel("print", self)
        self.label2.move(50,100)

        self.setWindowTitle("combine")
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.center()
    def fileselect(self):

        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Open Files", "C:\\Users\\", "(*.txt)")
        self.label2.setText(filename[0][0])

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

        self.combine = CombineClass()
    def initUI(self):
        self.fileselect = QPushButton("파일", self)
        self.fileselect.clicked.connect(self.combine)
        self.setWindowTitle("Text Master")
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.center()
        self.show()
    def combine(self):
        self.combine.show()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry, i use this website first time.
Please insert a tab for each sentence.

Comment: `import *` is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is really simple: create a method that sets the default values and then call that before displaying the window:

```py
class CombineClass(QDialog):
    # ...
    def reset(self):
        self.label2.clear()
    # ...

class MyApp(QWidget):
    # ...
    def combine(self):
        self.combine.reset()
        self.combine.show()
    # ...
```

Another possible solution is to create the dialog whenever it is required:

```
class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        # self.combine = CombineClass()

    def initUI(self):
        self.fileselect = QPushButton("파일", self)
        self.fileselect.clicked.connect(self.combine)
        self.setWindowTitle("Text Master")
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.center()
        self.show()

    def combine(self):
        self.combine = CombineClass()
        self.combine.show()
        print("after close")

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
```

Comment: Thanks.
But this method is not good when label is more than now.
If i have 100 labels, then i write 100 clear() lines.

Comment: @rut Do QLabels names have any patterns? Do you want to clean all QLabels?

Comment: QLabel is just sample.
In my real code, there are many labels, pushbuttons, boxes.
And they have no patterns...
I want to find more convinient function.

Comment: But this code has another problem. If I open a single window in the main window, no action will be possible on the main window after that.
So if I can't open another window with another button in main window.

Comment: This is well working. However, if i use this method, the first problem remains.
A problem exists when the main window is closed, but the new window is still there.
It doesn't matter much, but do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @rut I do not understand you, explain yourself better

Comment: I've solved it.
When pressing the close button on the main window, all windows are set to close at once by using another 'event'.
Thank you very much for your help.